# I can't display properly v-data-table data: ''Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object''

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex, vuetify.js

I'm starting a project in which I had to use Vue. I'm actually really new to this, so I'm learning on the go. I do apologize in advance since this question have answered before, however, I didn't really understand the solutions provided, which is why I'm here asking myself.

Well, I was trying to display some data on my Data Table (more specifically, v-data-table from Vuetify). I was able to get the data from the API, but, for some reason it doesn't show me anything. Thanks to Vuex I can see that the mutation worked because on the console on Google Chrome I can see the Array of objects. But as I said, it still does't show me a single thing on the table, it even says 'no data available'. Some errors that I get are things like '[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "items". Expected Array, got Object' and 'TypeError: this.items.slice is not a function'.

Here is the code from List.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container id="data-tables" tag="section">
    <div class="text-right">
      <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark color="primary" :to="{ name: 'UserCreate' }">
        <v-icon dark>mdi-plus</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
    </div>
    <base-material-card
      color="indigo"
      icon="mdi-vuetify"
      inline
      class="px-5 py-3"
    >
      <template v-slot:after-heading>
        <div class="display-2 font-weight-light">
          Lista de Empleados
        </div>
      </template>

      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        class="ml-auto"
        label="Search"
        hide-details
        single-line
        style="max-width: 250px;"
      />

      <v-divider class="mt-3" />

      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="users"
        :search.sync="search"
        :sort-by="['name', 'office']"
        :sort-desc="[false, true]"
        multi-sort
      >
        <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
          <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">
            mdi-eye
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon
            small
            class="mr-2"
            @click="editItem(item)"
            :to="{ name: 'UserUpdate' }"
          >
            mdi-pencil
          </v-icon>
          <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item)">
            mdi-delete
          </v-icon>
        </template>
      </v-data-table>
    </base-material-card>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'UsersTable',
  data() {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Nombre',
          value: 'empleado.nombre',
        },
        {
          text: 'Apellido',
          value: 'empleado.apellido',
        },
        {
          text: 'Dirección',
          value: 'empleado.direccion',
        },
        {
          text: 'Correo Electrónico',
          value: 'email',
        },
        {
          text: 'Teléfono',
          value: 'empleado.telefono',
        },
        {
          sortable: false,
          text: 'Actions',
          value: 'actions',
        },
      ],
      loader: true,

      search: undefined,
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('users/fetchUsers')
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['users']),
  },
  methods: {},
  mounted() {},
}
</script>
```

And the code from user.js, where the fetchUsers it's coming from.

```
import auth from '@/api/auth'

export const namespaced = true

export const state = {
  users: [],
}

export const mutations = {
  SET_USERS(state, users) {
    state.users = users
  },
}

export const actions = {
  fetchUsers({ commit, dispatch }) {
    auth
      .getAllAccounts()
      .then((response) => {
        commit('SET_USERS', response.data)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const notification = {
          type: 'error',
          message: 'There was a problem fetching users: ' + error.message,
        }
        dispatch('notification/add', notification, { root: true })
      })
  },
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the correct `user` from vuex, because is namespaced, change to:

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('users',['users']),
},
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried it, but when I do that, all the errors dissapear, but another one comes: 'Property or method "users" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render.'. And still not showing anything.

Comment: Well, tried that, for some reason now it says:  Error in render: "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded". I don't know what's happening now.

Comment: go to `...mapState('users',['users']),`

Comment: could you print the value odf  `this.users`?

Comment: Hi, I finally was able to fix it. when you gave me the alternative way of calling it, another error that I didn't notice pop up, it was something about the getters, so I basically went and did this on my users.js 

`export const getters = {
  users: (state) => {
    return state.users
  },
}`

After that, on computed, instead of mapState, I put a mapGetters: like this

`computed: {
    ...mapGetters('users', ['users']),
  },`

Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

MapState helper dosen't work the same way like the other helpers because the state module isn't registred in the global namespace. So namespacing your module will help or you do it in this way:

```
computed: { 
    ...mapState({
      users: state => state.FilenameOfYourModule.users
    })
}
```